# Eclipse microprofile metrics @Timed does measure time, always 0

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee, metrics, timed, microprofile

we have a problem with eclipse microprofile metrics @Timed annotation.
It does not seem to measure times (only counts number of calls).

Setup is with Payara 5 full.

Typical output via http://localhost:8080/metrics/application:

```
    # TYPE application:total_coffees_retrieved counter
application:total_coffees_retrieved 4
# TYPE application:total_coffees_consumed counter
application:total_coffees_consumed 4
# TYPE application:com_sebastian_daschner_hello_prometheus_coffees_retrieve_coffee_rate_per_second gauge
application:com_sebastian_daschner_hello_prometheus_coffees_retrieve_coffee_rate_per_second 1.4044150172871745
# TYPE application:com_sebastian_daschner_hello_prometheus_coffees_retrieve_coffee_one_min_rate_per_second gauge
application:com_sebastian_daschner_hello_prometheus_coffees_retrieve_coffee_one_min_rate_per_second 0.0
# TYPE application:com_sebastian_daschner_hello_prometheus_coffees_retrieve_coffee_five_min_rate_per_second gauge
application:com_sebastian_daschner_hello_prometheus_coffees_retrieve_coffee_five_min_rate_per_second 0.0
# TYPE application:com_sebastian_daschner_hello_prometheus_coffees_retrieve_coffee_fifteen_min_rate_per_second gauge
application:com_sebastian_daschner_hello_prometheus_coffees_retrieve_coffee_fifteen_min_rate_per_second 0.0
# TYPE application:com_sebastian_daschner_hello_prometheus_coffees_retrieve_coffee_mean_seconds gauge
application:com_sebastian_daschner_hello_prometheus_coffees_retrieve_coffee_mean_seconds 0.0
# TYPE application:com_sebastian_daschner_hello_prometheus_coffees_retrieve_coffee_max_seconds gauge
application:com_sebastian_daschner_hello_prometheus_coffees_retrieve_coffee_max_seconds 0.0
# TYPE application:com_sebastian_daschner_hello_prometheus_coffees_retrieve_coffee_min_seconds gauge
application:com_sebastian_daschner_hello_prometheus_coffees_retrieve_coffee_min_seconds 0.0
# TYPE application:com_sebastian_daschner_hello_prometheus_coffees_retrieve_coffee_stddev_seconds gauge
application:com_sebastian_daschner_hello_prometheus_coffees_retrieve_coffee_stddev_seconds 0.0
# TYPE application:com_sebastian_daschner_hello_prometheus_coffees_retrieve_coffee_seconds summary
application:com_sebastian_daschner_hello_prometheus_coffees_retrieve_coffee_seconds_count 4
application:com_sebastian_daschner_hello_prometheus_coffees_retrieve_coffee_seconds{quantile="0.5"} 0.0
application:com_sebastian_daschner_hello_prometheus_coffees_retrieve_coffee_seconds{quantile="0.75"} 0.0
application:com_sebastian_daschner_hello_prometheus_coffees_retrieve_coffee_seconds{quantile="0.95"} 0.0
application:com_sebastian_daschner_hello_prometheus_coffees_retrieve_coffee_seconds{quantile="0.98"} 0.0
application:com_sebastian_daschner_hello_prometheus_coffees_retrieve_coffee_seconds{quantile="0.99"} 0.0
application:com_sebastian_daschner_hello_prometheus_coffees_retrieve_coffee_seconds{quantile="0.999"} 0.0
```

mean, max, quantiles are all "0.0", while count works well (= 4).

We have tried multiple combinations of Payara/JEE/Microprofile versions, each with the same result.

Here are some code snippets (base is taken from https://github.com/sdaschner/hello-prometheus/tree/microprofile, only added @Timed)

Coffee-Bean:

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class Coffees {


    @Counted(name = "total_coffees_retrieved", absolute = true, monotonic = true)
    @Timed   
    public String retrieveCoffee() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep((int) (1000 * Math.random()));
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Coffees.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

        return "Coffee!";
    }

}
```

JAX-RS REST Resource:

```
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;

@Path("coffee")
public class CoffeesResource {

    @Inject
    Coffees coffees;

    @GET
    public String getCoffee() {
        return coffees.retrieveCoffee();
    }

}
```

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.sebastian-daschner</groupId>
    <artifactId>hello-prometheus</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.microprofile.metrics</groupId>
            <artifactId>microprofile-metrics-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version> <!-- also tried 1.0 and 1.1 -->
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>hello-prometheus</finalName>
    </build>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
</project>
```

Any ideas how to solve this?

**EDIT:** does not occur when requesting metrics with application/json

```
curl -H "Accept: application/json" http://localhost:8080/metrics/application
```

Issue is already solved for one of the next payara releases:
https://github.com/payara/Payara/issues/2970

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see something other than 0 you will need to have a method that takes some more time to execute! Simply incrementing a counter and returning a string like that will take hardly any time at all, definitely far less than 0.1 seconds, so you'll never see any value in your metrics.

Try adding `Thread.sleep(1500)` to the method to see if the timer logs 1.5 seconds.

Since `@Timed` gives you lots of statistics, you could also try `Thread.sleep(Math.random() * 1000)` to give you some variation in the amount of time it takes to execute and give you more interesting metrics to examine.

**Edit**: As mentioned in the comments below, there appears to be a bug in Payara Micro 5.182 which results in the timer not working.

Comment: @Counted(name = "total_coffees_retrieved", absolute = true, monotonic = true)
    @Timed   
    public String retrieveCoffee() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep((int)(1000*Math.random()));
                    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Coffees.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        coffeesConsumed.inc();
        return "Coffee!";
    }

Comment: I checked this out myself using both Payara Micro 5.182 and Thorntail 2.0.0.Final (rebranded WildFly Swarm). I found that it did not work in Payara Micro, but did work in Thorntail, so this is a bug in Payara Micro. The next step for you would be to open a GitHub issue on https://github.com/payara/payara/issues

Comment: thanks for your hints. Placed and issue for payara. And they answered quickly, that there is already a fix (for next release possibly). The bug does not occur, when requesting application/json.  For example curl -H "Accept: application/json" https://github.com/payara/Payara/issues/2838. Reference to Payara issue: [link](https://github.com/payara/Payara/issues/2970)